# How to use arrayadapter?

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite

I'm making an application that can search a table 'employee' and return results. How may I use an array adapter to do this? I'm new to android.

```
public class SimpleSearch extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
          doMySearch(query);
        }
    }
    public List<String> doMySearch(String query) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        Cursor c = db.query(
                "employee", 
                new String[] { "_id" }, // The column you want as a result of the Query
                "firstName like '%?%' OR lastName like '%?%' OR officePhone like '%?%'", // The where-Clause of the statement with placeholders (?)
                new String[] { query, query, query }, // One String for every Placeholder-? in the where-Clause
                );
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            result.add(c.getString(0));
        }
        c.close();
        return result;
    }


}
```

Comment: You should use SimpleCursorAdapter instead! please check this:http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/ and http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/347c5df5a13fec58?pli=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the ListActivity or a ListFragment and Populate them using an CursorAdapter.(SimpleCursorAdapter) is an implementation class

CursorAdapter can be populated from the List returned by your doMySearchMethod.

Comment: something like this?     
    public void doMySearch(String query) {
     
  cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee WHERE firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?", 
      new String[]{"%" + query.getText().toString() + "%"});
  adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
    this, 
    R.layout.emp_list_item, 
    cursor, 
    new String[] {"firstName", "lastName", "title"}, 
    new int[] {R.id.firstName, R.id.lastName, R.id.title});
  setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
    
    
    
}

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use array adapter, use [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) instead. If you need an example on using it, you can have a look at the [Notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html).